# Searching through an array using Ruby's array.index() method using wildcards

Tags: ruby, arrays, wildcard

I have created an array of tiles for a game board. Each element of my array is a hash with the following format:

```
{'x' => x, 'y' => y, 'base' => "base"}
```

The value of 'base' may be any string with no spaces.

I would like to find the index of any particular tile based on the X/Y values of the tile, regardless of the tile's base value.

My first thought on how to accomplish this is to search the contents of the array using the index() method, like this:

```
active_tile = tile.index({'x' => 3, ''y' => 2, 'base' => "WILDCARD_HERE" })
```

However, I have no idea how to implement a wildcard for this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I would also appreciate suggestions for better methods of storing and retrieving tiles if anybody knows that the method I'm using is definitely not an effective one.

For completeness, here is the entire piece of code I'm working with right now:

```
class Map
  attr_reader :max_ns   # maximum north-south size
  attr_reader :max_ew   # maximum east-west size
  attr_reader :tile     # the array of tiles

  def initialize(tall, wide)
    @max_ns = tall
    @max_ew = wide

    # Create an array of tiles with X/Y coordinates and a tile base type.
    @tile = []
    (1..tall).each do |y|
      (1..wide).each do |x|
        @tile.push({'x' => x, 'y' => y, 'base' => "ocean"})
      end
    end

    # Pick a spot to start a continent.
    rand_y = rand(3..tall - 2)
    rand_x = rand(3..wide - 2)
    continental_base = @tile.index({'x' => rand_x, 'y' => rand_y, 'base' => "ocean"})
    @tile[continental_base]['base'] = "land"

    # Now spiral around that spot, creating a larger land mass
    # finish writing the function to grab the array indices of the tile's neighbors first.
  end

  # Function to find the array indices of the tiles neighboring any given tile.
  def tile_neighbors(x, y)
    # First get the index of the tile with the given X & Y coordinates.
    cur_tile = @tile.index({'x' => x, 'y' => y, 'base' => "/\A(...)\z/"})
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using [Array#index](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-index) is sensible:

```
arr = [{x: 1, y: 2, base: "Yo, how ya' doin'?"},
       {x: 1, y: 3, base: "Hey, bro!"},
       {x: 2, y: 5, z: 4 }]

target = { x: 1, y: 2 }
arr.index { |h| h.values_at(*target.keys) == target.values } #=> 0

target = { x: 1, y: 3 }
arr.index { |h| h.values_at(*target.keys) == target.values } #=> 1

target = { y: 5, x: 2 }
arr.index { |h| h.values_at(*target.keys) == target.values } #=> 2

target = { x: 2, y: 'cat' }
arr.index { |h| h.values_at(*target.keys) == target.values } #=> nil
```

Comment: It took me a few moments to wrap my head around that, but it seems pretty obvious now. I was completely unfamiliar with the values_at method of arrays and the keys method of hashes. Thank you and Mark Reed both!

Answer (score 0):

First, a solution using your current data structure. When you call `index` with a regular parameter, it does exact matching, so that won't work.  But if you pass a *block*, then it will return the index of the first element for which the block returns true:

```
cur_tile = @tile.index { |tile| tile['x'] == x && tile['y'] == y }
```

However, I'm not sure why you wouldn't just use a two dimensional array of tiles where `x` and `y` are the indexes into the array, so that `@tiles[0][0]` is the one where x and y are both 0:

```
[  [ base00, base01, base02, ... ],
   [ base10, base11, base12, ... ] ]
```

Comment: Mostly it's because I'm brand new to this and just figuring it out as I go along! Thank you for the help, each_with_index and select are working great, but now I'm off to explore the two-dimensional method!

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to find the index of any particular tile based on the X/Y values of the tile, regardless of the tile's base value.

Well, then, make it easy on yourself, and create a hash of all the tiles, based on their X/Y values:

```
array = [
  {'x' => 1, 'y' => 1, 'base' => "asdf"},
  {'x' => 2, 'y' => 1, 'base' => "sdfg"},
  {'x' => 1, 'y' => 2, 'base' => "dfgh"},
  {'x' => 2, 'y' => 2, 'base' => "fghj"}
]

hash = array.map{ |h| ['%i/%i' % [ h['x'], h['y'] ], h] }.to_h
hash 
# => {"1/1"=>{"x"=>1, "y"=>1, "base"=>"asdf"},
#     "2/1"=>{"x"=>2, "y"=>1, "base"=>"sdfg"},
#     "1/2"=>{"x"=>1, "y"=>2, "base"=>"dfgh"},
#     "2/2"=>{"x"=>2, "y"=>2, "base"=>"fghj"}}
```

Finding a hash based on the X/Y coordinates suddenly becomes easy:

```
hash['1/1'] # => {"x"=>1, "y"=>1, "base"=>"asdf"}
```

If you want to quickly search for bases still, you can easily create a similar hash:

```
hash = array.map{ |h| [h['base'], h] }.to_h
hash 
# => {"asdf"=>{"x"=>1, "y"=>1, "base"=>"asdf"},
#     "sdfg"=>{"x"=>2, "y"=>1, "base"=>"sdfg"},
#     "dfgh"=>{"x"=>1, "y"=>2, "base"=>"dfgh"},
#     "fghj"=>{"x"=>2, "y"=>2, "base"=>"fghj"}}
hash['asdf'] # => {"x"=>1, "y"=>1, "base"=>"asdf"}
```

And, there's nothing that says the two can't all be part of the same big hash, as long as there are no key collisions:

```
hash1 = array.map{ |h| ['%i/%i' % [ h['x'], h['y'] ], h] }.to_h
hash2 = array.map{ |h| [h['base'], h] }.to_h
hash = hash1.merge(hash2) 
# => {"1/1"=>{"x"=>1, "y"=>1, "base"=>"asdf"},
#     "2/1"=>{"x"=>2, "y"=>1, "base"=>"sdfg"},
#     "1/2"=>{"x"=>1, "y"=>2, "base"=>"dfgh"},
#     "2/2"=>{"x"=>2, "y"=>2, "base"=>"fghj"},
#     "asdf"=>{"x"=>1, "y"=>1, "base"=>"asdf"},
#     "sdfg"=>{"x"=>2, "y"=>1, "base"=>"sdfg"},
#     "dfgh"=>{"x"=>1, "y"=>2, "base"=>"dfgh"},
#     "fghj"=>{"x"=>2, "y"=>2, "base"=>"fghj"}}
hash['1/1'] # => {"x"=>1, "y"=>1, "base"=>"asdf"}
hash['asdf'] # => {"x"=>1, "y"=>1, "base"=>"asdf"}
```

It's easy to locate all tiles matching a pattern:

```
hash.values_at(*hash.keys.grep(/^a/)) # => [{"x"=>1, "y"=>1, "base"=>"asdf"}]
hash.values_at(*hash.keys.grep(/h$/)) # => [{"x"=>1, "y"=>2, "base"=>"dfgh"}]
hash.values_at(*hash.keys.grep(/dfg/)) # => [{"x"=>2, "y"=>1, "base"=>"sdfg"}, {"x"=>1, "y"=>2, "base"=>"dfgh"}]
```

or:

```
hash.values_at(*hash.keys.grep(%r#^1/#)) # => [{"x"=>1, "y"=>1, "base"=>"asdf"}, {"x"=>1, "y"=>2, "base"=>"dfgh"}]
hash.values_at(*hash.keys.grep(%r#/2$#)) # => [{"x"=>1, "y"=>2, "base"=>"dfgh"}, {"x"=>2, "y"=>2, "base"=>"fghj"}]
```

The biggest advantage to using a hash for this is it is extremely fast. Whether you want the first tile on the board, the last, or one anywhere else, the lookup speed is just as fast. Arrays are great for holding stuff you want to process sequentially, but they're terrible when you want to find something quickly, but that's where Hashes are useful.

Comment: Wow, your description of the array map method makes so much more sense than the documentation in [the Ruby documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-map). 

Thank you for the breakdown of arrays vs hashes for lookup speed, too. I think I am gonna rewrite my class a bunch of times until all this new info sinks in.